# laravel add conditions in belongsToMany relationshaip

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In index controller i don't need any condition so data retrieves very clearly with all relational models.

```
 $questions = Question::with('user','courses','subjects')->take(10)->orderBy("id","DESC")->get();
```

This return the question list with all related data like `user` `courses` and `subject`
But in courses controller when try to retrieve data with same and adding condition for course slug then its return error.

```
$questions = Question::with('user','courses','subjects')->where("slug",$course)->take(10)->orderBy("id","DESC")->get();
```

Because its adds this condition in question table query so there are no `slug` coloumn.
And When i retrieved with `course` class it return correct result but the `subjects` and `users` are missing

```
$questions = Course::with("question")->where("nick_name",$course)->orWhere("slug",$course)->orderBy("id","DESC")->take(10)->get();
```

Then how can i get all related data.
And the course model has

```
public function question(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Question','university_questions')->take(10);
}
```

and question model have

```
 public function courses(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Course','course_questions');
}
public function subjects(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Subject','subject_questions');
}
public function years(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\QuestionYear');
}
```

What is missing here please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to get multiple relations you need to pass array,like this

```
$questions = Course::with([
              'questions.user',
              'questions.courses',
              'questions.subjects'
              ])
              ->take(10)
              ->where("slug",$slug)
              ->orderBy("id","DESC")
              ->get();
```

Comment: But the slug is not in question table it's in course table.

Comment: oh,sorry my mystake,if you want to add condition to related model you need to use callback function,I'll edit answer now

Comment: Thanks, But i also tried this, it return the all questions and if question have course then this where condition add there. Means i'll get all question and this condition apply on only course if slug found it return course otherwise null.

Comment: then I'll suggest to do with the reversed option
like
$course = Course::with(['questions.users,'questions.subjects'])->whereSlug($slug)........

Comment: I am also thinking about that, But that means i have also created relation with all tables in course model and subject also ?

Comment: well if you have Course -> Question relation exists and Question->User,Question->Subject exist (I'm assuming that you have them) writing ->with(['questions.users','questions.subject'] will return you all related questions for courses with users and subjects tables

Comment: Cheers,have nice day :)